# can i use a notify_url with paypal subscribe button

Tags: paypal

Can I use a notify_url with a paypal subscribe button?  If yes will the notify_url be called every month when the payment is made?

for example if i put in the form:

```
<input type='hidden' name='notify_url' value='payment-success.php'>
```

will that script be called for every payment made?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `notify_url` in subscription button.Every month, PayPal will just use the same notify_url you setup when you created this subscription button.

Basically, its that you cannot update the notify_url for subcription buttons.

If you want to update the notify_url , only way is to cancel and create the subscription with new notify_url.

Comment: can give me some example, because the buttons for subscriptions are ofSDK:actions.subscription.create({
                  'plan_id': params.subscription.paypal_id,
                  'application_context': {